# `hover` pseudo-class not working

Tags: html, css

This is my css file, till now I have made a simple navigation bar. 
But the point is for my `<a>` elements in the navigation bar, when I try to style them both in case `a` and `a:hover` they work only when I give `!important`. What is happening. Is there a specificity issue ?

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');

.navbar {
  background-color: #b6b5b4;
  border-style: solid;
}

.container {
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
}

body {
  font-family: Lato;
}

a {
  color: black !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-right {
  background-color: #aeaeae;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #dfdfdf !important;
}
```

I am new to css and html.

Comment: Please include your html to allow us to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You imported Bootstrap, which has default CSS styling. What you're basically doing, is trying to overwrite those styles. However, Bootstrap seems to be taking precedence over your CSS (probably due to the order of the imports in your HTML file), thus requiring `!important`. The `!important` tag makes sure that, that particular style cannot be overwritten or, is always displayed over others.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
```

If your ordering is like this, Bootstrap styling will be displayed, unless you use `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is parent divs like `.container` (may be, dont have your html structure) is having `background-color` css. 
This css will override the `hover` css on child `<a>` element. `!important` keyword is made only for this purpose. It does not allow other styles to override itself. 
Thats why you should use `!important` keyword in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
a:hover { background: #dfdfdf !important;}
```

use this one

Comment: I know that !important works, my point is why. What is overriding my style if I don't use !important

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If u give like this

```
a {
  background-color: black !important;
}
```

**!important** overrides the hover state styles also.

```
 a {
      background-color: dfdfdf;
    }
```

doesn't work.

give your style like this

```
a {
   background-color: black;
  }
//remove !important
```

remove `!important` from `<a>` tag. Hover state works normally.
Let me know if u get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have default `css` file with styles with its nesting! quick fix for this issue:  assign `class` for `<a>` with your styles!

```
a.my-class {
  color: black;
   font-weight: bold;
}
a.my-class:hover {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}
```